# How to download files using DownloadManager and Log their name and path (Android)?

Tags: java, android, android-download-manager

I am able to download files ( mp4 videos) in Android using DownloadManager set to a specific path, but when I try to get the file names from the path it outputs a ".lock" file as the name of my files. I want the name of the files I have downloaded:

```
File[] files = fileDirectoy.listFiles();
```

> This statement (as below) returns null for the files array. The folder does contain four .mp4 videos

The code that I used is listed below.

```
File fileDirectoy = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uriVideo);
request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(getApplicationContext(), fileDirectoy.toString(), myListOfDocuments.get(i).get("name").toString() + ".mp4");

//todo: Enable this to download videos downloadManager.enqueue(request);

//Lists Files in Local Storage

if(fileDirectoy.exists()) {
    File[] files = fileDirectoy.listFiles();
    for(File file : files) {
        Log.d("MyLog","File name: "+file.getName());
        Log.d("MyLog","File path: "+file.getAbsolutePath());
        Log.d("MyLog","Size :"+file.getTotalSpace());

    }
} else {
    Log.d("MyLog", "File directory does not exist");
}
```

Not sure why this behavior is taking place.

Comment: `fileDirectoy =  getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();` getFilesDir() does not match getExternalFilesDir() which you use in `request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir()...`

Comment: `request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(getApplicationContext(), fileDirectoy, myListOfDocuments.get(i).get("name").toString() + ".mp4");`Oh Oh Oh. I only see it now. You are using a full path there (and a wrong one). You should only supply a name for one folder. And the filename yes.

Comment: `request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(getApplicationContext(), Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, myListOfDocuments.get(i).get("name").toString() + ".mp4");` @blackapps I corrected this statement to use the `Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS` which now saves the mp4 videos in the apps downloads folder but I cant list the files inside with `File directory = new File(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);` followed by `File[] files = directory.listFiles();` The `files` array comes up as null, not sure why. could you provide clafication on your previous comments - They might be misinterpreted

Comment: Please adapt the code in your post. To be it as what i suggested and you use now. Dont use comments for your code as all in all its unreadable.

Comment: @blackapps Post has been adapted to be what you have suggested. Thanks for the help

Comment: `File directory = new File(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);` That is no valid path/directory at all which you could easily find out yourself if you used `directory.exists()`.  Earlier i told you that setDestinationInExternalFilesDir() would save in getExternalFilesDir(). So use that here too. Adapt the code in your post too when you use getExternalFilesDir() and still have questions.

Comment: @blackapps I have adapted the post. The 'files' array returns null even when using the same directory for DownloadManager. I think I am incorrectly setting a file directory path. is this so? (And I appreciate the help)

Comment: `File fileDirectoy = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();` My god. I did not say that you should change that line. Bring it back to only the download directory. Then read my comment(s) again.